# Hibernate @OneToMany where discriminatorValue = 'SOMETHING'

Tags: jpa, hibernate-onetomany

Table `pdp_billable_field_state` carries configuration for various fields.
Owner of configuration can be any number of Entity`s
This configuration is same for each entity that matches the `@DiscriminatorValue`

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "entity_type")
@Table(name = "pdp_billable_field_state")
public abstract class EntityFieldStateJpa extends AuditableJPA {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      @Column(name = "id")
      private Long id;

      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name = "status_id")
      private StatusJpa status;

      @Column(name = "field", columnDefinition= "varchar(255)")
      private String field;
      private boolean disabled;
      private boolean hidden;

    }


@DiscriminatorValue("PURCHASE")
public class PurchaseEntityFieldStateJpa extends EntityFieldStateJpa {}



@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "pdp_purchase")
public class PurchaseJpa {

   // omitted

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
   // i do not have a join_column since all records with entity_type PURCHASE map to all purchases, as these are configurations used by all purchases. Should i try and introduce @JoinTable maybe?
   @Where(clause = "entity_type='PURCHASE'")
   private List<PurchaseEntityFieldStateJpa> fieldStates;

}
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what your requirements are, but it sounds like `@Formula` is what you want. That being said, why do you feel you need the physical `fieldStates` property? It seems using a query to retrieve the `fieldStates` would be more natural

Comment: So i need to fetch list of PurchaseEntityFieldStateJpa with each PurchaseJpa. Practically collection of  PurchaseEntityFieldStateJpa will be the same for each purchase. I am looking to avoid writing dedicated query for this. Did this clarify the problem?

Comment: In that case you definitely need some variant of the `@Formula` annotation. See [here](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/how-to-use-the-hibernate-joinformula-annotation-with-a-onetomany-jpa-association/1461) for a similar use case